# Scroll problems - CoordinatorLayout + AppBarLayout + ViewPager with Fragments containing RecyclerViews

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have the following layout:

```
<CoordinatorLayout layout_height="match_parent">

    <AppBarLayout layout_height="match_parent">
        <CollapsingToolbarLayout layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView> //Fullscreen picture
            <LinearLayout> //Some text and icons

            <Toolbar layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"> //No title
            <TabLayout layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"> //Drawn on top of the invisible Toolbar 

        </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </AppBarLayout>

    <ViewPager layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FloatingActionButton/>

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now, the ViewPager has 3 fragments, each with a RecyclerView inside it. I believe this should be a regular design pattern. The ViewPager sits below the AppBarLayout, which starts full screen, so you have to scroll down to see the ViewPager content.

The problem is **when I fling on the AppBarLayout, the fling event prevents any further scroll until it stops flinging (until velocityY = 0). But this takes up to 2 or 3 seconds sometimes**, so in the meanwhile, the touchpad remains unresponsive.

What is worse, if I try to scroll on one of the children RecyclerViews, the screen will flicker so badly and the RecyclerView will suddenly appear at the scrolled position once the AppBarLayout fling has ended. This is horrible!

I've already tested [this smooth AppBarLayout library](https://github.com/henrytao-me/smooth-app-bar-layout) and while it fixes some issues, it introduces some other bad ones (the ViewPager is drawn on top of everything, and not below the TabLayout).

**UPDATE: FULL XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ActivityActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <!-- ALSO TRIED app:layout_behavior="com.package.utils.FlingBehavior" -->


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="center|top"
            app:expandedTitleMarginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_extra"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="70dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/background_picture"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:tintMode="screen"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.8">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Probando probando"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="120dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/icon"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/activities_options_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabContentStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/activities_options_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="20dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ico_share" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

AND ONE OF THE FRAGMENTS, THEY ARE ALL THE SAME:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_large"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Help!

Thanks

Comment: add all of your xml file including your fragment xmls

Comment: Ok, I just addded them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i used this for the same purpose

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.cafeagahi.app.AccountActivity">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>    
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp_pages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you handle pinning the tabs to the top when scrolling down, without a Toolbar?

Comment: by this design, the appbar layout will hide and tablayout will be the top view in screen

Comment: did you use my design? did it solve your scrolling problem?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. Sorry but it doesn't solve the problem. The recycler view still flickers. Have you tried to set the AppBar full in height in reproduce the problem I've described?

Comment: I'll try the full height Appbar